# How to implement a in-program-documentation in c# WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, documentation

For a student project we want to implement a help / documentation form.

In this form we want to display text and images that should describe / help with the application.

The information could be represented in some kind of FAQ with questions and answers. These questions could the grouped into different categories like: (General information, function X, function y, function z, ...)

Unfortunately I don't know what would be a good way to implement / display this. The following possibilites come into my mind:

- Create a PDF for each category, use a treeview for the category selection and display the PDF for the selected category
- Use a richtext textbox in the design time and set the editable function to false in the runtime. (I do dislike this idea)

I also think that updating the documentation will also be a issue. I guess I'd prefer to use an external program to write the documentation and to just include it into the program.

Has anyone some advice on this issue?
(C# 4.0, Winforms)

Comment: Easiest to make and maintain would be simple (embedded) HTML and a WebBrowser.

Comment: @Henk Holtermann:Ok. But the simple refers to HTML without images, right? How can I show embedded images without copying them into the file system?

Comment: A Help file with Images? Don't get carried away. I believe you can intervene in the loading on the Browser control, but I've never done that.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: If you post your approach as an answer, I would accept it

Comment: No, I was just suggesting some vague ideas. If you've got it working it would be nice if you would post a summary as answer to yourself. That's encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to use embedded HTML Help files. These use standard HTML for presentation, and can be embedded in your application. Check out [HTML Help for Winforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms669985) on MSDN.